# protect admin area in Flask app fromNormal users accesss

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

hello i have a problem with my /admin route in my flask app when anyone can see mywesite/admin page they dont have access to admin methods but they can see the page i try to do this with the code blow But i still have the problem :

```
from flask_admin import expose, BaseView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_login import current_user
from flask import abort


class CustomView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_admin:
            return self.render('admin/index.html')
        else:
            return abort(403)

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_admin

    def is_visible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_admin


class CustomModelView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_admin


class UserView(CustomModelView):
    column_list = ('username', 'active', 'email')

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_admin
```

in my main app file i have this :

```
from flask import Flask
from .extentions import db, ckeditor, mail, migrate, bootstrap, user_login_manager, 
basic_auth
from flask_admin import Admin

def create_app():
    application = Flask(__name__)
    application.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(application)
    bootstrap.init_app(application)
    ckeditor.init_app(application)
    mail.init_app(application)
    migrate.init_app(application, db)
    basic_auth.init_app(application)
    return application


app = create_app()
admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(CustomView(name='My View', menu_icon_type='glyph', 
menu_icon_value='glyphicon-home'))
admin.add_view(UserView(User, db.session))

@app.route('/admin')
@admin_only
@login_required
def admin_index():
    return render_template('admin/index.html')
```

please tell me where is my problem on how can i fix this thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

i find my answer and i post it here maybe help someone

i create a MyHomeView class and inherit from AdminIndexView:

```
from flask_admin import expose, BaseView, AdminIndexView

class MyHomeView(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        new_cafe = db.session.query(NewCafe).all()
        new_users = db.session.query(NewUser).all()
        new_subs = db.session.query(NewSubscriber).all()
        count = db.session.query(NewCount).first()
        # check current user is admin and authenticated
        if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_admin:
            return self.render('admin/index.html',
                           new_cafe=new_cafe,
                           new_users=new_users,
                           new_subs=new_subs,
                           count=count)
    else:
        return abort(403)
```

and in the main file when i create a admin from Admin i pass the MyhomeView class as index_view like this :

```
from flask_admin import Admin
from app.admin_views.admin_page import MyHomeView

admin = Admin(app, index_view=MyHomeView(), template_mode='bootstrap4')
```

with this method not admin users when try to access my /admin view get 403 Error You can Replace this With any Error You Want